# How to display image in Django templates with the same image name

Tags: django

In `views.py`

```
def list_image(request):
    if form.is_valid():
        list_image = form.cleaned_data['list_image']
        return render(request, "list.html", ...) // How to give list_image to query_image

def query_image(request):
    if form.is_valid():
        query_image = form.cleaned_data['query_image'] 
        list_image = ??? //I also want to get list_image here,and display in all_image.html
        return render(request, "all_image.html", ...)
```

I can display image in **list.html** or **query.html** well.

Now I want to display images from `list_image` and `query_image` in **all_image.html**.But how?

Comment: It is not clear to me at all what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for that,I have edited it

Comment: are you expecting the list_image to be sent as a form data for the "query_image" views? if yes, then the answer is trivial. if no, then are you expecting the views to be called one after the other? (like in a wizard-type view)

Answer (score 0):

If query_image and list_image are came from the same form, you can do this:

Try to

```
def query_image(request): #it woul be better to rename it to all_image
    if form.is_valid():
        query_image = form.cleaned_data['query_image'] 
        list_image = form.cleaned_data['list_image']
        my_context = {'query_image': form.cleaned_data['query_image'],
                      'list_image': form.cleaned_data[]
                      #... any other data}
        return render(request, "all_image.html", my_context)
```

And you have to make sure that all_image.html renders list_image somehow (using django templates `for`, for example)

Comment: But query_image and list_image are not came from the same form

Comment: @Aison could you please describe UX for this case? How do you want to instantiate both forms? And what are you trying to do exactly? I'm not sure that working with two forms in the same time with a way you described is a good and robust idea.